# How to Insert Null values into sqlite table in objective c

Tags: objective-c, coalesce

I am getting the empty strings from the web service and I'm inserting data into the sqlite table.
Now i am trying to retrieve the data with coalesce function
This is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(senderName,senderMobileNumber,senderEmailId) FROM recommendations
```

then empty strings are displaying

Comment: Maybe there are empty strings in `senderName,senderMobileNumber,senderEmailId`. `COALESCE` returns first not null, not empty

Comment: Keep null rather than empty strings in sendername,sender.....

Comment: @Justin yes i have empty string in senderName that's why I'm trying to insert null value into the senderName. if I'm inserting NULL, Nil, nil its inserting as a <null>